# how to mock/stub out a specific custom validator when doing unit testing in grails?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

Lets say i have a domain A which has a custom validator for property P

```
static constraints = {

        P validator: { val, obj ->

            (A.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A cei WHERE cei.event.id = ?", [val.id])[0] <= 1)

        }
```

In the unit test how can i mock the P property of domain A so that i don't get the error i am getting when running unit test. The error i get when running unit test is shown below. The setup code instantiates domain A as shown below.

```
void setUp(){

inv = new A(P: rg).save(flush: true)
```

Error is

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: String-based queries like [executeQuery] are currently not supported in this implementation of GORM. Use criteria instead.
```

Note: These are fake code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option for me, is encapsulate the inner code of the validator inside a service. And then, mock that service in your unit test.

But the error thrown is that executeQuery is not available, but criteria is.
So change your code for using a criteria instead.

```
P validator: { val, obj ->
   A.withCriteria{
      eq('event', Event.findById(val.id))
      projections{
         count('id')
      }
   }[0] < = 1
}
```

Comment: Try to use A.countByEvent(Event.findById(val.id)) <= 1 is simplier and maybe works also